# (Mac OS) Swap function between Right Option key and Left Arrow key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro

My Left Arrow key was broken. So I want swap function between Right Option key and Left Arrow key. Please help me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). Save this file as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open KeyRemap4MacBook, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting.